# Como logro que este juego random funcione correctamente con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, random

Estoy apenas aprendiendo `javascript`y para practicar tuve la idea de hacer un juego de inglés/español. El juego consiste básicamente en que en el titulo aparece un modismo colombiano y abajo en unos cuadros algunas definiciones que podrían ser de ese modismo. Si escojes la equivocada, el cuadro y la definición desaparecen, si escoges la correcta sale un titulo diciendo "Well done! Let's play again press enter."

Hasta el momento llevo esto: [juego](https://codepen.io/lina-paredes/pen/roadPN)

Hay diferentes cosas que todavía no logro hacer funcionar, pero las dos que me preocupan más básicamente son:
1. Que no logro que al hacer clic en la respuesta correcta la reconozca como correcta y salga el mensaje para jugar de nuevo.
2. Como las opciones salen de manera random  son más que el número de cuadrados a veces no sale la respuesta del modismo que aparece y no sé que puedo hacer para asegurarme que ocurra eso.

Comment: ¿Presenta errores en consola ? al parecer como primer problema es que hace falta una llave de cierre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> click en la respuesta correcta

para controlar que hagan click en la respuesta correcta te conviene pasar el evento en la funcion del listener, es decir `squares[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){...` esto te permitirà leer el target del click con el metodo `.target`.

Yo por ejemplo lo que hice fue controlar que la respuesta fuerà la correcta gracias a la clase usando `e.target.className`, podrias usar tambien `e.target.id` ecc..., y aca nos conectamos a tu otra pregunta

> como me aseguro que este siempre la respuesta correcta

para asegurarse de que esto ocurra, tenes que crear un nuevo array, en el caso de aca abajo yo utilize `var answers = []"` para guardar las respuestas que vamos a inserir mas adelante en las casillas de respuesta.

vos estas tomando el modismo con un numero random que tenes en la variable `randomSlang` ya que `meaning` y `modismos` tienen los mismo indices, para la traduccion del modismo o al revez, aprovechamos para sacar la respuesta correcta con la misma variable e insertamos el valor en el array que terminamos de crear. `answers.push(meaning[randomSlang])`.

ahora sabemos que de los 6 casilleros, 1 ya esta ocupado es decir que nos quedan 5, en este punto hacemos un ciclo `for` para sacar los meaning restantes en modo aleatorio. yo en este ejemplo use el for siguiente :

```
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * meaning.length);
    //SI EL ELEMENTO ES IGUAL A LA RESPUESTA CORRECTA DIMINUIMOS i Y SEGUIMOS
    if (meaning[randomindex] === meaning[randomSlang])
         i--;
    else 
         answers.push(meaning[randomindex]);
}
```

como podes ver al interno tiene un if, esto sirve para no repetir la respuesta correcta mas de una vez. a este punto para que no sea evidente que la respuesta 1 es siempre la correcta, le agregamos un buen `answers.sort()` para mezclar el array.

una vez terminado el ciclado, ya tenemos el array de respuestas completado  y utilizando el ciclo for que habias creado inicialmente, modificando los paramentros : `for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++)` en este momento, vamos a controlar el contenido que estamos metiendo en la pagina, para encontrar nuestra respuesta correcta `if (answers[i] === meaning[randomSlang])` si coresponden le agregamos la una clase que puede ser "correcta" en este modo `squares[i].className += " correcta";`

y conectandonos finalmente a la primera, vemos si la respuesta elejida es la correcta : `if (e.target.className === "square correcta")`

ejemplo funcionante :

```js
var modismos = [
 "¿Que mas?",
 "¡Listo!", 
 "¡Deli!",  
 "Rumbear",
 "Inmamable",
 "Guacala",
 "Chevere",
 "¡De una!",
 "¿Quién dijo yo?",
 "¡Que vaina!",
 "Ni modo",
 "Para nada",
 "¡Ya dijo!",
 "Ni loco!"
];

var meaning = [
 "it's actually just a local way to say 'What's up?'",
 'Ready, done, ok', 
 'Yummy or delicious',
 'To party', 
 'Annoying', 
 'Yuck',
 'Cool',
 'An enthusiastic way to say “yes, let’s do it!”.',
 'Anyone?',
 'Too bad',
 'Oh well or never mind',
 'Oh well or never mind',
 'Yeah right!',
 'No way'
];

//UTILIZA ESTA VARIABLE PARA SACAR TAMBIEN EL MEANING CORRESPONDIENTE
var randomSlang = Math.floor(Math.random()* modismos.length);

//CREA UN NUEVO ARRAY PARA ALMACENAR LOS MEANING QUE QUIERAS INSERTAR EL LA PAGINA
var answers = [];
//INSERIS EL MEANING CORRESPONDIENTE A LA PREGUNTA 
answers.push(meaning[randomSlang]);
document.getElementById("respuesta01").innerHTML = modismos[randomSlang]

//AGREGAS UN FOR PARA INSERTAR LAS RESPUESTAS QUE FALTAN, EN ESTE CASO COMO YA TENES UNA TE FALTAN 5
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    var randomindex = Math.floor(Math.random() * meaning.length);
    //SI EL INDEX ALEATORIO ES IGUAL AL INDEX DE LA RESPUESTA CORRECTA, DIMINUIMOS i Y SEGUIMOS
    if (meaning[randomindex] === meaning[randomSlang])
         i--;
    else 
         answers.push(meaning[randomindex]);
}
//MEZCLAMOS EL ARRAY DE LAS RESPUESTAS PARA ASEGURARNOS DE QUE ESTEN SIEMPRE MEZCLADAS
answers.sort();

var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
 squares[i].textContent = answers[i];
  if (answers[i] === meaning[randomSlang])
      squares[i].className += " correcta"

//Adicionar el clicklistener a los cuadrados
 squares[i].addEventListener('click', function(e){
//Comparar la definición escogida con la correcta
    if (e.target.className === "square correcta"){
         console.log("That's right! Well done octopus!");
       document.getElementById("respuestaCorrecta").innerHTML = "That's right! Well done octopus!";
    } else {
       this.style.background ="#1a1a1a";
       this.style.color ="#1a1a1a";
   }  
})};
```

```css
body{
 font-family: "Montserrat";
 background-color: #1a1a1a;
 color: #e6e6e6;
}

body > .container {margin-top:60px;}

.navbar-brand {
 height: auto; 
 padding: 0;
}
.navbar-inverse {
    top: 0; 
    right: 0; 
    left:0;
    z-index: 10; 
    background-color: #1a1a1a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #1a1a1a;
    position: fixed;
    border: none;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 10px; 
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav >li>a{
 color: #ffffff;
 background-color: #6666ff;
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 border-radius:50%;
 display: table-cell;
 vertical-align: middle;
 text-align: center; 
}

.jumbotron{
 color: #55552b;
 margin-top:60px;
}

h1{
 color: #ffffff;
 text-align: center;
 height: 80px;
 line-height: 80px; 
}

#container{
 margin: 0 auto;
 max-width: 600px; 
}

.square{
 width: 30%;
 height: 50px;
 padding-bottom: 30%;
 float: left;
 margin: 1.66%;
 color:#293d3d;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #668cff;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Spanish Game</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Spanish.css">
</head>
<body>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#hamburguer" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </button>
   <a href="HappyChristmas.html" class="navbar-brand">The O <br> and <br> The S</a>
  </div>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <!-- Barra de menu de la izquierda
  --> 
  </ul>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="hamburguer">
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    <!-- CABALLITO DE MAR -->
    <li><a href="#">S</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div> 
 </div> 
</nav>

 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-lg-12">
     <div class="jumbotron">
     <h2>Let´s learn some spanish!</h2>
           <p>This are some of our colombian slang. Can you guess their respect meaning?</p>
     </div>
   </div>
   <div class="col-lg-12">
     <h1>The colombian slang is: <text id="respuesta01"></text></h1>
     <h3 id="respuestaCorrecta"></h3>
   </div>
   <div id="container">
     <div class="square" id=1></div>
     <div class="square" id=2></div>
     <div class="square" id=3></div>
     <div class="square" id=4></div>
     <div class="square" id=5></div>
     <div class="square" id=6></div>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="Spanish.js"></script> 
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

espero que te sirva, exitos.

Comment: GRACIAS! Sé que la pregunta era muy larga pero mil gracias por tomarte el tiempo de responderla y con tanto detalle, de verdad me aclara muchas cosas!